# Multiple -XX command-line options on a JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am working on an experimental JVM and I am getting a threshold value as an -XX command-line option from the user: `VMOptions.addFieldOption("-XX:", "FlareAllocationThreshold", AllocationProfiler.class, "The number of the Flare objects to be allocated before the Allocation Profiler starts recording. (default: 100)");` which works fine.

Now I am trying to evolve it a bit and give to user the capability to set multiple thresholds.

The first thing that I've tried was just to change the `FlareAllocationThreshold` from int to String such as `"100, 200, 300"` and then using the following method to transform it into integers

```
    public static int[] stringToInts(String line) {
        //String line = "100, 200, 300";
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        int[] ints = new int[parts.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        }
        return ints;
    }
```

Unfortunately I have several restrictions on my JVM, such as the prohibition of creation new objects during that process, so the usage of the `stringToInts()` is forbidden.

So my question is the following, could I have somehow an -XX command-line option which gives the user the opportunity to choose how many thresholds he/she wants to use such as: `-XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_1=100 -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_2=200 -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_3=300` for 3 thresholds etc?

Comment: Why do you ask us? How do we know what you can or cannot have in *your* JVM?

Comment: Also it's absolutely possible to convert a string to a number without allocating objects.

Comment: @apangin well that conversion would be the easiest solution. Forget my JVM, let's say that my question was for the hotspot one, is that possible to do something like that -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_1, -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_2, -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_3, -XX:FlareAllocationThreshold_4 etc?